# R build interaction matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a set of item in 5 list which are within a list. What I have done is constructed a matrix (`tt_matrix`) that contains items that are present in the one of the 5 lists (columns 1 to 5), but also present in the other corresponding list of 5 lists (rows 1 to 5). In the example I gave below it is essentially 5 lists vs the same 5 lists. Is there a more elegant/faster way of filling the matrix, perhaps one without 3 for-loops (see code bellow)?

```
#matrix
tt_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow=length(tlist_sub), ncol=length(tlist_sub))

#Make hash lookup table
tdf_env_sub <- new.env()`

tdf_names_sub <- c("0_754", "755_859", "860_1119", "1120_1839", "1840_2330")

#total unique reads
unq_rds <- unique(unlist(tlist_sub))
```

`tlist_sub` :

[tlist_sub dput()](http://1drv.ms/1NJMwEl)

```
[[1]]
 [1] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2110:14509:11072" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2113:20433:7925" 
 [3] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2113:20433:7925"  "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1104:25512:15827"
 [5] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:18636:20589" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2112:8742:14213" 
 [7] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:19363:25050" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2101:20792:17286"
 [9] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1107:10609:25094" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1108:2957:17646" 

[[2]]
 [1] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2110:14509:11072" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2113:20433:7925" 
 [3] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2113:20433:7925"  "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1104:25512:15827"
 [5] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:18636:20589" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2112:8742:14213" 
 [7] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:19363:25050" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2101:20792:17286"
 [9] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1107:10609:25094" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1108:2957:17646" 

[[3]]
 [1] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1107:16335:18024" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1111:13719:2995" 
 [3] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1113:28025:20668" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2114:7408:16585" 
 [5] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2113:26942:12013" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1111:23385:5935" 
 [7] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2110:14585:3232"  "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2113:14890:10443"
 [9] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2114:12846:16485" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1102:19118:14376"

[[4]]
 [1] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:11972:17459" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:6800:24111" 
 [3] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1110:10908:18899" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2101:20791:9350" 
 [5] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1109:16168:10651" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2101:20791:9350" 
 [7] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1102:26099:21517" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1113:24350:7463" 
 [9] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1101:19654:26608" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1114:12659:5227" 

[[5]]

 [1] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1105:21509:10358" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2104:26287:12446"
 [3] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2109:12091:22350" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2112:12838:7167" 
 [5] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1105:21509:10358" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2104:26287:12446"
 [7] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:2109:12091:22350" "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1112:21242:8988" 
 [9] "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1112:4191:7532"   "HWI-M02293:152:000000000-AH78U:1:1112:21242:8988"
```

Filling the hash  table:

```
#Place each bin into hash table
for(item in seq_along(tdf_names_sub)){
  tdf_env_sub[[tdf_names_sub[item]]] <- tlist_sub[[item]]

}
```

Filling the matrix:

```
pb_2 <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(unq_rds), style = 3)
#loop over each read and check bin occupancy
#eapply()
#Loop through all the unique reads
for(i in seq_along(unq_rds)){
  #Loop throught all the bins x-way
  for(x in seq_along(tdf_names_sub)){
    #Loop through all the bins y-way
    for(y in seq_along(tdf_names_sub)){
      #If read is in bin1 and bin2
      if((unq_rds[i] %in% tdf_env_sub[[tdf_names_sub[x]]]) && (unq_rds[i] %in% tdf_env_sub[[tdf_names_sub[y]]])){
        #Add 1 to matrix
        tt_matrix[x,y] <- tt_matrix[x,y] + 1
      }

    }

  }
  setTxtProgressBar(pb_2, i)
}
```

Output:

```
tt_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    9    9    0    0    0
[2,]    9    9    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0   10    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    9    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    6
```

Comment: Instead of posting the `print` output of `tlist_sub` you should post `dput()` output. (It's a real PITA to try to reconstruct a list like that.)

Comment: @42- Added the dput() output.